# Чего не хватает в проекте, чтобы работали ссылки на внешние ресурсы?

Tags: canvas, webview, phonegap, ionic

Пытаюсь собрать свое первое приложение для андроид с помощью Cocoon или PhoneGap. Когда тестирую в браузере все ссылки, внешние ресурсы (картинки, мультимедиа, запросы к бд, WebSocket) - все работает, однако после сборки в apk никакие внешние ресурсы не загружаются, несмотря на то, что при установке самого приложения в телефоне (Lenovo A800) приложение запрашивает разрешение на доступ в Интернет. Пробовал включать разные плагины от Cordova - не помогло, пробовал менять в Cocoon webview на webview+ или canvas+ - не помогает.
   Для простоты сделал самый простой проект - страничку с двумя изображениями, одно из которых в Интернете:

http://coockoo.ru/!test/blank/
Apk: http://coockoo.ru/!test/blankapk.zip

В браузере оба изображения отображаются, а на устройстве - только одно

Comment: Вероятнее всего, домены на которые делаются запросы необходимо добавить в [белый лист]( https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/appdev/whitelist/)

Comment: <!-- Добавил в config.xml -->

<access origin="*" /> 
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
  
 добавил  в index.html
 
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">

  не помогло

Comment: Хотя улучшения есть: при клике по ссылке выдает ошибку "не удалось подключиться к серверу". Пробовал без http://-

Comment: В build.phonegap.com не заработало, а в cocoon.io вроде работает, спасибо @Uranus но не работает WebSocket